# Creating static C library to use in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I am trying to create a static library for [gumbo-parser](https://github.com/google/gumbo-parser) to use in my iOS app. I have tried to make "Cocoa Touch Static Libray" by adding all source files. When I build the library it builds and creates libgumbo.a However, Debug-iphonesimulator/include/gumbo.h file is basically empty

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface gumbo : NSObject

@end
```

What is the proper way to create a gumbo library(for simulator and device) so that I can use this library in my Swift project? Basically, I want to create a Swift framework which will consume gumbo library.

Comment: Look at the bottom of: https://github.com/google/gumbo-parser, it looks like you need to use https://github.com/programmingthomas/ObjectiveGumbo or https://github.com/tracy-e/OCGumbo

Comment: I try to create a swift framework. You can't use Bridging Header in frameworks.